# Offline Network Policy sometimes makes Picasso stop working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, image-loading

I am trying to implement a Data Saver mode in my application. If the user turns it on, the app should only load those images, that are already stored in the cache.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBitmapLoaded for item #" + position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBitmapFailed for item #" + position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPrepareLoad for item #" + position);
        }
    });
```

Most of the time, it works perfectly.
The problem is that there are some cases, when only the onPrepareLoad gets called, and after that neither the onBitmapLoaded nor the onBitmapFailed gets called.

The ImageViews I am trying to fill with the images loaded by Picasso are items of a RecyclerView. Whenever I scroll away and then back, so whenever the item gets loaded again by the RecyclerView, it loads the image without any problem.

Have anybody experienced this behaviour before?

EDIT:

```
05-17 15:44:07.433 13570-13570/org.meightsoft.dailyfun.debug I/RecentsAdapter: onBindViewHolder for item #7
05-17 15:44:07.434 13570-13570/org.meightsoft.dailyfun.debug I/RecentsAdapter: onPrepareLoad for item #7
```

Comment: WHere is your stacktrace?

Comment: I've edited. Now it is there.

Comment: Have you considered the image isn't saved locally?

Comment: It is actually saved locally, because the next time, it tries to load it using offline network policy, it loads without any problem